# Changing the BackgroundResource of a ListView Object while it's off screen

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

newbie doing a course assignment here.

I'm making a Xamarin C# application where you create a List of objects which are displayed in the UI with the goal of keeping track of turns in a tabletop / board game.
To show who is having their turn, when you hit a rotateButton the Object having their turn has their ListView cell change colour, while the others are set to white.
If the screen is too small or has any objects off screen, the application crashes when hitting the rotateButton.

How do I prevent this crash? Can I keep the data in memory so that when you scroll down the Unit having their turn will be blue? Is ListView capable of this?

Here's how the button works

```
Button _rotateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.rotateButton);
        int rotatePrevious = -1;
        int rotateCurrent = 0;

        _rotateButton.Click += delegate
        {
            int rotateCount = ItemUnits.Count();

            if(rotateCount != 0)
            { 

            if (rotateCurrent == 0)
            {
                _rotateButton.Text = "End Turn";

            }

            if(rotatePrevious != -1)
                {
                    ItemUnits[rotatePrevious].IsSelected = false;
                }

                if (rotateCurrent == rotateCount)
                {

                    foreach(ItemUnit iu in ItemUnits)
                    {
                        iu.IsSelected = false;
                        View inactiveView = listView.GetChildAt(ItemUnits.IndexOf(iu));
                        inactiveView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.colorPrimary);
                    }
                    rotateCurrent = 0;
                    rotatePrevious = -1;
                    _rotateButton.Text = "New Round";
                }

                else
                {
                    ItemUnits[rotateCurrent].IsSelected = true;

                    foreach (ItemUnit iu in ItemUnits)
                    {
                        if (iu.IsSelected == true)
                        {
                            View activeView = listView.GetChildAt(ItemUnits.IndexOf(iu));
                            activeView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.colorAccent);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            View inactiveView = listView.GetChildAt(ItemUnits.IndexOf(iu));
                            inactiveView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.colorPrimary);
                        }

                    }


                    rotateCurrent++;
                    rotatePrevious++;

                    if (rotateCurrent == rotateCount)
                    {
                        _rotateButton.Text = "End Round";
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: What specific line is causing the crash?  What is the exception?

Comment: It's just a null reference exception when it tries to change the BackgroundResrouce because it's trying to refer to a ListView cell that's not on the screen, which I assume means it doesn't exist in the context. So I'm looking for a way around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you can add a `setSelectedId` method in the Adapter. Then change the background color like following code.

```
   public class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Meeting>
{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<Meeting> listMeeting;
    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, List<Meeting> listMeeting)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listMeeting = listMeeting;
    }

    public override Meeting this[int position] => listMeeting[position];

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return listMeeting.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return listMeeting[position].Id;
    }
    private int selectedId = -1;
    public void setSelectedId(int position)
    {
        selectedId = position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_view, null);


        var txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.idLogin);
        var txtDepart = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.idContact);
        var txtEmail = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Place);
        txtName.Text = listMeeting[position].idLogin.ToString();
        txtDepart.Text = listMeeting[position].idContact.ToString();
        txtEmail.Text = listMeeting[position].Place;

        if (selectedId == position)
        {
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);

        }
        else
        {
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);

        }


        return view;
    }


}
```

Use this method, Change the color by Postion.

```
    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapter.setSelectedId(Int32.Parse(edtidLogin.Text));
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Here is my Actvity code.

```
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        lstViewData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
         edtidLogin = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtidLogin); 
        var btnChange = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnChange);
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact=1, idLogin=1, Place="test1" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 2, idLogin = 1, Place = "test2" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 3, idLogin = 1, Place = "test3" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 4, idLogin = 1, Place = "test4" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 5, idLogin = 1, Place = "test5" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 6, idLogin = 1, Place = "test6" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 7, idLogin = 1, Place = "test7" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 8, idLogin = 1, Place = "test8" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 9, idLogin = 1, Place = "test9" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 10, idLogin = 1, Place = "test10" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 11, idLogin = 1, Place = "test11" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 12, idLogin = 1, Place = "test12" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 13, idLogin = 1, Place = "test13" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 14, idLogin = 1, Place = "test14" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 15, idLogin = 1, Place = "test15" });
        listSource.Add(new Meeting() { idContact = 16, idLogin = 1, Place = "test16" });

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, listSource);
        lstViewData.Adapter = adapter;

        btnChange.Click += BtnAdd_Click;

    }

    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapter.setSelectedId(Int32.Parse(edtidLogin.Text));
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Having some issue using my code mixed in with your methods and I keep getting out of range exceptions and some other issues, so I was just trying to get it working... still not luck yet. I'll get back to you when I've got it running.

Comment: Took some fiddling but I got it to work using the adapter.setSelectedId approach. I didn't use the method you posted but the method you provided worked in using my solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Lu A further question would be do you know how to set it so that none of the items are selected?